# How to limit Firebase HTTP/Callable function request size?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Can we limit the HTTP/Callable function request size that is coming from the client? I know we can check the request with the function once it arrives but then its too late as we need to download the unwanted request first in order to verify it.

**I am wondering if there is a way to prevent malicious users from flooding functions with requests of 10 mb in size.** First I thought I can block the user once I detect invalid request but I can see now even if the user is blocked nothing is stopping the user from calling the function. I can of course prevent this user from accessing backend features but the request is still sent from the client and **I am afraid it may affect the quotas and our bills.**

Comment: I found informations here informative on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948561/are-google-cloud-functions-protected-from-ddos-attacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is no elegant solution to your problem. Any service with a public endpoint will suffer from the same type of attack and thousands more. You will need to place your endpoints behind load balancers, CDNs and implement attack management with web application firewalls (Cloud Armor).

1. Inbound data transfers are free so this helps mitigate the cost portion.
2. Unless necesary don't publish HTTP callable functions. Call these functions from your other services. This enables load balancers, caching and firewalls.
3. Deploy your functions behind Apigee.
4. Implement smarts into your design to detect attacks and block access using services like Cloud Armor. Simple logic will detect large payloads and then block the offending IP address in the firewall. This requires #2 however.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. Good to know inbound data transfers are free, I missed that. Do you or @DougStevenson know if Firebase will detect and block a malicious user who is attempting too many calls to FB Database or Functions? Or will it just scale (depending on the plan) and load balancers, caching and firewalls are the only option to prevent this type of attacks?

Comment: Is Cloud Armor similar to AWS Shield and can be used with Cloud Functions and Firebase products?

Comment: Yes, similar to AWS Shield and WAF. No cannot be put in front of Cloud Functions. That is why I mentioned item #2. Don't make your endpoints public.

Comment: @Dave - for your first comment. Attacks are so common (I mean expect them), that you need to design your systems to be attacked and then test that your can handle attacks. Whenever I launch a new instance in the cloud, within minutes attacks are happening. There are just so many "script kiddies" just hitting IP addresses. This means you need (almost always) a load balancer and firewall to deflect and manage attacks. For example, my personal website which covers security topics, is hit hundreds of times per hour just with login attempts. The important point is that you cannot stop the attacks.

Comment: You can only design your systems to handle attacks.

Comment: Yes, Firebase and Cloud Functions will scale. Some attacks can overload even cloud resources - services do have a requirement of time to scale.

Comment: Thanks again @JohnHanley for all the information and your time. I am not a server expert and that is why I decided to go for one of the serverless solutions hoping that issues like this will be taken care of for me (Load Balancers, Firewalls). I am a bit surprised this topic is not mentioned in any firebase security video/document I found. I know any system can be hacked/overloaded but don't like the idea any "script kiddie" can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct - nothing is stopping someone from invoking any callable or HTTP function.  But you can't limit the size of the payload differently than the hard limit of 10MB you mentioned.  However, it's highly unlikely that someone will do this maliciously.  If you would like to see this as a feature, [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).