# Protect an unauthenticated Cloud Run endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run

when I make an unauthenticated (public) Cloud Run endpoint to host an API, what are my options to protect this endpoint from malicious users making billions of HTTP requests?

For $10 you can launch a Layer 7 [HTTP flood attack](https://hackernoon.com/we-survived-a-ddos-attack-that-peaked-at-250k-requests-per-second-it-cost-us-10-b0bdfe028dd2) that can send 250k requests per second. Let's assume your Cloud Run endpoints scale up and all requests are handled. For invocations alone, you will pay $360,-/hour (at $0.40 per million requests).

Note that there is a [concurrency limit](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency_values) and a [max instance limit](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits) that you might hit if the attack is not distributed over multiple Cloud Run endpoints. What other controls do I have?

As I understand, the usual defenses with [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/) and [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/) are bound to the [Global Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview), which is unavailable for Cloud Run, but is available for Cloud Run on GKE.

Comment: Could you elaborate the "project this endpoint from malicious users"?

If it's an authenticated endpoint, is it supposed to receive requests from any callers? Do you mean so sort of rate limiting per caller?

Comment: The question asks about "unauthenticated" (=public). It seems to be referring to denial of service attacks from a lot of clients or just one client which could be classified as abusive/harmful client.

Comment: That's correct. I reworded the question to give an example of a HTTP flood attack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unauthenticated invocations to a Cloud Run service with an IAM Cloud Run Invoker role set to the allUsers member type, I would expect the answer to be the same as those provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953862/7911479

specifically:

> Cloud Functions sits behind the Google Front End which mitigates and absorbs many Layer 4 and below attacks, such as SYN floods, IP fragment floods, port exhaustion, etc.

It would certainly be great to get a clear Y/N answer on Cloud Armor support.

[Edit]: I have been thinking on this quite a lot and have come to the following conclusion:

if you expect you are likely to become a victim of an attack of this type then I would monitor your regular load/peak and set your account's ability to scale just above that load. Monitoring will allow you to increase this as your regular traffic grows over time. It appears to be the only good way. Yes, your service will be down once you reach your account limits, but that seems preferable in the scenario where you are the target.

An idea which I am yet to try is [a protected route with Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating#end-users) and [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

Comment: Thank you! I am specifically interested in the Layer 7 (HTTP) protection. I added an extra paragraph to the question to explain.