# Is there a way to restrict public access from firebase callable could functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

**Firebase callable cloud functions** can be accessed via client sdks, which requires a valid auth context for authentication and authorization. But and at the same time it is exposed as an HTTP endpoint, thus can be called but will receive an unauthorized response. 
My questions is, is there a way to completely restrict public access for a callable cloud functions? since firebase will charge cloud functions based on function executions. Even to return an unauthorized response, the request has already gone through to the function, thus during a DDoS attack this could be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support for rejecting a request to a Cloud Function before it reaches your code. If you want such functionality consider setting up Cloud Endpoints in front of your Cloud Functions.

The best you can with just Cloud Functions do is check whether the caller is authorized as the first thing in your function code, so that you reduce the amount of time the function is active. You'll still be charged for the invocation in that case, but you'll minimize the GB-seconds and CPU-seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Found  a good thread on the same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948561/are-google-cloud-functions-protected-from-ddos-attacks/49282490

Answer (score 1):

I tried out as @Frank suggested using google cloud run to deploy and ESP container which can by used to invoke private cloud functions. A detailed overview is described in the documentations itself.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#deploy_endpoints_proxy

Answer (score 0):

Above given answer by @Frank van Puffelen is perfect but you can utilize a trik to restrict the access by securing that route. Here is the example,

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.scheduleSampleJob = functions.https.onRequest((req , res) => {
     let auth = req.header('Authorization');

     if(auth == 'YOUR_API_AUTHORIZATION_KEY'){
         // valid Authorization key, process the call
     }else{
         //send forbidden if Authorization key not valid
         return res.status(403).send('Access is Forbidden'); 
     }
});
```

Now, if you want to call the endpoint, It will require a **Authorization** header in request having value your secret key.

As firebase cloud function can also be used with firebase-auth, you can create custom logic to allow access to users having auth only and restrict the access for public excluding your app's authentic users.

Comment: the problem is, still this is prone to DDoS attacks coz the authentication logic resides inside our code and anyone with the function url can invoke this. Since we return 403 Forbidden means that the request has gone through right?

Comment: Yes, request still pass through. But it's the only way to authorized access as firebase doesn't have such facility so far. Maybe you can protect the route with Cloudflare. But I didn't use Cloudflare with firebase function till now.

Comment: I tried  google endpoints which has a service proxy (ESP) where we could rate limit. We could do the same authentication inside ESP, with this way we could remove or keep the logic in our code. This way our cloud functions can be made private and let only ESP invoke.