# Firebase cloud functions pricing for denied requests

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking to deploy an application fully on firebase and I'd like to know how cloud functions pricing works if my endpoints gets attacked.

Costs are calculated by invocations, CPU/memory usage and time to run the function, so, even if I add some middleware to authenticate the request, returning 403 asap, I'd still get charged for the request, right?

Does firebase have any sort of protection to these type of scenarios?

What are the options to not get overcharged in my credit card?

Comment: well the most common answer you're going to get is `set budget limits` which will at least keep you safe from getting overcharged. And there is a tool called Cloud Armor https://cloud.google.com/armor/ check it out if it helps. And see this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948561/are-google-cloud-functions-protected-from-ddos-attacks