# Firebase Auth Blocking Functions: Pricing and Security

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently working on implementing Firebase Auth Blocking Functions within my application, specifically the `beforeCreate` and `beforeSignIn` functions. I have a couple of questions related to these functions;

1. Are Auth Blocking Functions also vulnerable to DDoS Attacks?
   I'm concerned about the security of my application, particularly when it comes to DDoS attacks. Are Firebase Auth Blocking Functions inherently secure against DDoS attacks? Do they have any built-in mechanisms to mitigate or handle such attacks? If not, what are some best practices to ensure the security and availability of these functions, especially in scenarios involving potential DDoS threats?
2. Payment for Firebase Auth Blocking Functions:
   Are Firebase Auth Blocking Functions subject to charges similar to other cloud functions on Firebase? I would like to know if I should expect any additional costs when using these auth security functions, or if they are covered under the regular Firebase auth charges.

Any insights, experiences would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of Cloud Functions there is nothing specific about the triggers coming from Firebase Authentication/Identity Platform. So for your DDoS question, see [Are Google Cloud Functions protected from DDoS attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948561/are-google-cloud-functions-protected-from-ddos-attacks)

When you implement Cloud Functions for blocking triggers from Firebase Authentication/Identity Platform, you will pay for those Cloud Functions as indicated in the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing). This is separate from any charges you may already get from your use if Firebase Authentication/Identify Platform.